# PLS-00201: identifier when running oracle stored procedure through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am running to run an oracle stored procedure in rails, but I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parse' for
#<Mysql2::Client:0x00000008ef4310>):
```

in the following line:

```
   cursor = connection.parse(sql)
```

This is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter:  mysql2
  database: db1
  username: user1
  password: *****
  host:     *****
  port:     3306

db1_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: user2
  password: ****
  database: ****
  host: *****
  port: 3306

db2_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: user3
  username: ******
  password: ******
  host: *****
  port: 3309

db3_development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: user3
  username: *****
  password: *****
```

these are my 2 model classes:

```
module Sts

  class StsLtd < Sts::Base
    def number
        errormsg = nil
        errorcode = nil
        sperrormsg = nil
        vpan = nil

        sql =
      "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
        8042049440330819','32', 'TEST', '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
       END;"

       connection = self.connection.raw_connection
       cursor = connection.parse(sql)

         cursor.bind_param(:errormsg, nil, String, 1000)
         cursor.bind_param(:errorcode, nil, String, 1000)
         cursor.bind_param(:sperrormsg, nil, String, 1000
             cursor.bind_param(:vpan, nil, String, 1000)

       cursor.exec

       vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg, vpan = cursor[:vpan], cursor[:errormsg], cursor[:errorcode], cursor[:sperrormsg]
       cursor.close
       vpan
    end
  end
end
```

sts.rb:

```
module Sts

  PKG_LTD ="PKG_LTD"

  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection = "db3_#{Rails.env}"

  end
end
```

I am not sure why it is throwing mysql parse error, when the specific set of code is only trying to connect to the oracle database and running the oracle stored procedure.

EDIT: I was able to fix the parse error by removing the '=' from the following line:

```
establish_connection = "db3_#{Rails.env}"
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (ORA-06550: line 1, column 53: PLS-00201:
>   identifier 'VAULT' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored):

My stored procedure works fine if I hardcode "VAULT" as follows:

```
    sql =
  "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
    8042049440330819','32', 'VAULT', '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
```

But if I pass it as a function argument and call it, i get the above error:

```
    sql =
  "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
    8042049440330819','32', #{vault_cd}, '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
```

Comment: At what point does it throw the error? As soon as you start the server? Only when you fire the stored procedure? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: yes when I do a binding.pry and get to `cursor = connection.parse(sql)` from the above code, it throws the error.

Comment: But if you don't do any binding does it still error?

Comment: yes, i get the same error and tracing to the same line: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parse' for #<Mysql2::Client:0x0000000c6d88d0>):`

Comment: Yes, but there's a reason for a stack trace rather than just a single error line. Include more of your stack trace to maybe help people help you. Post your stack trace, or at least 5 or 10 lines of it, if it is really long. What do the web server logs say?

Comment: Sorry figured out the issue. the following line is the culprit   `establish_connection = "db3_#{Rails.env}"`. There should be no `=`. However i get a different error `OCIError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` on this line `cursor.bind_param(:errormsg, nil, String, 1000)`

Comment: Please edit your question with updates and an actual stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I ran into 3 different errors while running the stored procedure.

The first error was:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parse' for
#<Mysql2::Client:0x00000008ef4310>):
```

It was fixed by changing the code from:

```
establish_connection = "db3_#{Rails.env}"
```

to

```
establish_connection  "db3_#{Rails.env}"
```

The second error was:

> OCIError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

It was fixed by updating the sql from:

```
  sql =
  "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
    8042049440330819','32', 'VAULT', '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
```

to add symbols

```
  sql =
  "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
    8042049440330819','32', 'VAULT', '0',:vpan, :errormsg, :errorcode, sperrormsg);
```

The final error was:

> ActionView::Template::Error (ORA-06550: line 1, column 53: PLS-00201:
>   identifier 'VAULT' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored):

For some reason it was not interpreting this as a string.

So I had to add single quotes even for  #{vault_cd} to make it work:

```
 sql =

      "BEGIN #{Pkgltd::PKG_LTD}.GET_PAN('
        8042049440330819','32', '#{vault_cd}', '0',vpan, errormsg, errorcode, sperrormsg);
```